# Узнать количество загруженных файлов

Tags: php, javascript

Не могу разобраться, как узнать количество загруженных файлов на сервер через js.

В php разобрался - их количество записывается в файл, с каждым загруженным файлом число увеличивается на 1. Файлы загружаются через ифрейм, без перезагрузки страницы.

В js через setInterval делаю запрос к php файлу, который отдает информацию о содержимом файле, который содержит количество загруженных файлов. Но запрос происходит тогда, когда все файлы будут загружены. Даже если напрямую обращаться к файлу с количеством загруженных файлов, запрос будет после того, когда будут загружены файлы. Запросы делаю через $.get (jquery).

================

Думаю, нужно смотреть в сторону AS, верно? Там вроде все это проще можно проделать.

================

Что делается:

JS:

```
function check () {
        setInterval(function () {
            $.get('/check.php, function (res) {
                console.log('progress', res);
            });
        }, 1000);
}

function send () {
        var iframe = '<iframe name="tname" id="tname" style="display: none;"></iframe>';
        $('body').append(iframe);
        $('form').submit(); // у формы таргет на ифрейм
}

check();
send();
```

PHP:

Файл, куда загружаются файлы:

```
<?
        $finfo = 'files_amount.txt';
        $filesAmount = 0;
        foreach ($files as $file) { // $files - сериализованный массив $_FILES
            sleep(3); // для проверки
            $temp_path = '/temp/'.$file['name'];
            move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], $temp_path);

            $filesAmount += 1;
            file_put_contents($finfo, $filesAmount);
        }
?>
```

Файл проверки (check.php):

```
<?
        $finfo = 'files_amount.txt';
        echo file_get_contents($finfo);
?>
```

Так же попробовал обернуть send() в setTimeout, запросы на проверку отправлялись, но когда приходило время выполнить метод send() - запросы проверки отправляться перестали.

Comment: вам нужен прогресс загрузки ? iFrame обязательное условие ? можно так (с FormData) http://codular.com/javascript-ajax-file-upload-with-progress

не получается, потому что апач отдает управление php, **после** того как все файлы загружены

Comment: Спасибо, изучу ссылку. Мне не прогресс загрузки одного файла нужен, а именно количество загруженных (оно, например, записывается в файл). А как еще загружать файлы без перезагрузки страницы, как не через ифрейм? Вроде как это везде через него реализуется.
====
Понял, там используется XMLHttpRequest 2, который может загружать файлы... и которого не поддерживает IE < 10.

Comment: @rimlin как вариант, отправляйте через iframe "по одному" файлы. или смотрите сюда: https://github.com/drogus/jquery-upload-progress там нужен модуль для apache/nginx